# Is it possible to create a standalone MSI from Installshield Express?

Tags: windows-installer, installshield

I have made an installation package in Installshield Express.  The only MSI I can find is not standalone and relies on files it expects to be in the same directory as the MSI file.

Do I need to use Premier or Professional?

Answer (score -1):

I don't have Express but I think what you are asking for is a media type called "Compressed" vs "Uncompressed".  I can't imagine Express can't do this.